# Jordan form corresponding to Discrete time impulse response.

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, linear-control

Which of the following discrete-time state-space models $(A,B,C,D)$ of the form

$x(t+1)=Ax(t)+Bu(t), \quad y(t)=Cx(t)+Du(t), \quad t\in \mathbb{N}$

with $A$ in jordan form has its impulse response given by

$h(t)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  \delta(t-1)+2^{t-1} \ \text{for} \ t = 1,2,3,...\\
                  0 \ \text{for} \ t = 0,\\
                \end{array}
              \right.$
$\quad$ where $\delta = 0^t = \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  1 \ \text{for} \ t = 0\\
                  0 \ \text{for} \ t = 1,2,3,...\\
                \end{array}
              \right.$

Answer:

$A) \quad \left[ \begin{array}{c|c} A&B \\ \hline C&D \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} 2&0 &1 \\ 0&0&1 \\ \hline 1&1&0 \end{array} \right]$

$B) \quad \left[ \begin{array}{c|c} A&B \\ \hline C&D \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} 1&1&1 \\ 1&1&0 \\ \hline 2&0&0 \end{array} \right]$

$C) \quad \left[ \begin{array}{c|c} A&B \\ \hline C&D \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c|c} 2&1 \\ \hline 1&0 \end{array} \right]$

$D) \quad \left[ \begin{array}{c|c} A&B \\ \hline C&D \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} 2&0&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ \hline 1&0&0 \end{array} \right]$

$E) \quad \text{None of the above}$

I know that the DT impulse response output equals: $y(t) = CA^{t-1}B$

so $h(t) = CA^{t-1}B$.

Entering a few values of $t$ into $h(t)$
gives: $h(t) = 1 \ \text{for} \ t = 1, $ $ \ h(t) = 2 \ \text{for} \ t = 2, $ $h(t) = 4 \ \text{for} \ t = 3, $ All answers fit this patern.

I know that $2^{t-1}$ means that the jordan form has at least a $2$ in it so $B$ is incorrect.

$A$ is the right answer, but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: Your first value for the impulse response seems off, namely it should be $h(1)=2$. Did you also try evaluating $C\,A^{t-1} B$ for any of the proposed solutions?

Comment: for $t=1$, $CA^{t-1}B$ gives $A=B=2, C=1, D=0$ which leaves only $A$ and $B$ as possible answers. Entering further values of $t$ produces the same results for $A$ and $B$. The fact that $B$ does not have a $2$ in it makes $A$ the only correct answer. Thanks.